# add key values to a table in pysimplegui

Tags: key, pysimplegui

using pysimplegui to search a dataframe and printing the values as keys shown below

when using sg.Text as below it works fine but I cant get the top row to align based upon the values that print out

```py
right_col = [[sg.Text('PRODUCT: ', size=(200, 1), key='product',font='Courier 50')],

[sg.Column([[sg.Text('RAW MATERIAL                                                            REF NO.                   %W/W' ),]])],
                            [sg.Text('A '), sg.Text(size=(50, 1), key='raw_a',font='Courier 12'),sg.Text(key='raw_a_ref'),  sg.Text(key='raw_a_%')],
                            [sg.Text('B '), sg.Text(size=(50, 1), key='raw_b',font='Courier 12'),sg.Text(key='raw_b_ref'),  sg.Text(key='raw_b_%')],
                            [sg.Text('C '), sg.Text(size=(50, 1), key='raw_c',font='Courier 12'),sg.Text(key='raw_c_ref'),  sg.Text(key='raw_c_%')],
                            [sg.Text('D '), sg.Text(size=(50, 1), key='raw_d',font='Courier 12'),sg.Text(key='raw_d_ref'),  sg.Text(key='raw_d_%')],
                            [sg.Text('E '), sg.Text(size=(50, 1), key='raw_e',font='Courier 12'),sg.Text(key='raw_e_ref'),  sg.Text(key='raw_e_%')],
                            [sg.Text('F '), sg.Text(size=(50, 1), key='raw_f',font='Courier 12'),sg.Text(key='raw_f_ref'),  sg.Text(key='raw_f_%')],
                            [sg.Text('G '), sg.Text(size=(50, 1), key='raw_g',font='Courier 12'),sg.Text(key='raw_g_ref'),  sg.Text(key='raw_g_%')],
                            [sg.Text('H '), sg.Text(size=(50, 1), key='raw_h',font='Courier 12'),sg.Text(key='raw_h_ref'),  sg.Text(key='raw_h_%')],
                            [sg.Text('I '), sg.Text(size=(50, 1), key='raw_i',font='Courier 12'),sg.Text(key='raw_i_ref'),  sg.Text(key='raw_i_%')],
                            [sg.Text('J '), sg.Text(size=(50, 1), key='raw_j',font='Courier 12'),sg.Text(key='raw_j_ref'),  sg.Text(key='raw_j_%')],
                            [sg.Text('K '), sg.Text(size=(50, 1), key='raw_k',font='Courier 12'),sg.Text(key='raw_k_ref'),  sg.Text(key='raw_k_%')],
                            [sg.Text('L '), sg.Text(size=(50, 1), key='raw_l',font='Courier 12'),sg.Text(key='raw_l_ref'),  sg.Text(key='raw_l_%')],


                            [sg.Text('procedure'),





                            sg.Text(size=(20, 10), key='procedure')]
]

# together
layout = [[sg.Column(left_col, element_justification='c'), sg.VSeperator(), sg.Column(right_col)]]
```

So to resolve the alignment issue I would like to put the keys in a table.  However, whatever way I have put them in a table as described https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pysimplegui/pysimplegui_table_element.htm , I have no success

I am explaining the changes to the keys in the loop so I would assume they are read easily.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8UXt.png)

Comment: [sg.Text('A '), sg.Text(size=(50, 1), key='raw_a',font='Courier 12'),sg.Text(key='raw_a_ref'),  sg.Text(key='raw_a_%')]

Answer (score 0):

Set the size of columns same at the headings and rows, better to use same elements, `sg.Text` here, for better alignment.

Example Code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

headings = ("RAW MATERIAL", "REF NO.", "%W/W")
items = "ABCDEFGHIJKL"
w1, w2, w3 = widths = (50, 20, 20)
left_col = [[sg.Text("Left Column")]]

right_col = [
    [sg.Text('PRODUCT: ', expand_x=True, key='product',font='Courier 50')],
    [sg.Text(heading, size=width) for heading, width in zip(headings, widths)]] + [
    [sg.Text(item, size=w1, key=f'raw_{item.lower()}'),
     sg.Text(f"row_{item.lower()}_ref",  size=w2, key=f"raw_{item.lower()}_ref"),
     sg.Text(f"raw_{item.lower()}_%",size=w3, key=f"raw_{item.lower()}_%")]
        for item in items] + [
    [sg.Text('procedure'), sg.Text(size=(20, 10), key='procedure')],
]

# together
layout = [[sg.Column(left_col, element_justification='c'), sg.VSeperator(), sg.Column(right_col)]]
sg.Window("Title", layout).read(close=True)
```

[image]